# Chromium extension/userscript to shrink the Android Developer header

Tags: android, userscripts, chromium

The [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/) has a very large header -- one that becomes obnoxious when I increase the font size in Chromium (because the whole things scales).

I [found a UserScript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/82939) that reduces the size of the header. It works in Firefox, but I'm using Chromium (which has [some support](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) for UserScripts). In Chromium, the script successfully reduces the height of the header, but doesn't extend the body. (There's a big blank area at the bottom of the screen.)

To get the script partially working in Chromium and I made two changes: change @include to @match and insert the @required javascript into my script. In the Chromium debugger, the last if (that does the resizing) is skipped.

I tried setting the height of the content in the script (after the if):

```
$('#doc-content').height('auto');
```

That looks right, but now there's no scrollbar. Adding overflow didn't help either:

```
$('#doc-content').overflow('scroll');
```

I don't really know what I'm doing (I'm new to js and jquery), but I hope that someone else will see **why the Android docs body doesn't fill the empty space when I shrink the header**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/82939) has been updated and now works for Chrome.

(Worked for me on Chromium 10.0.648.133 (77742) Ubuntu 10.10.)